# regexp inside insert query in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Why inside insert extract part expression doesn't work, but:

```
select toDateTime(extract('2016-08-02 07:06:18+00:00', '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}'))

SELECT toDateTime(extract('2016-08-02 07:06:18+00:00', '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}'))

┌─toDateTime(extract('2016-08-02 07:06:18+00:00', '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}'))─┐
│                                                                           2016-08-02 07:06:18 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I get this error when inserting:

```
 DB::Exception: Cannot parse datetime: Cannot parse DateTime from String.
```

Comment: clickhouse version 20.3.20

Comment: I handled with date insert using parseDateTimeBestEffort without regexp

Answer (score 0):

BTW, about inserts https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-date_time_input_format

```
$ cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/date_time_input_format.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
   <profiles>
       <default>
           <date_time_input_format>1</date_time_input_format>
       </default>
   </profiles>
</yandex>
```